# Count the unique values in a Column based on criteria in 2 different columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working in Google Sheets. I have 3 columns:

```
ID     Region    Year
101      US      2014
102      EU      2014
103      US      2014
102      US      2015
102      EU      2014
```

I would like to count the number of Unique IDs for each year and region. Thus, the results would be:

```
2014 US: 2
2014 EU: 1
2015 US: 1
```

Here are the limitations I have to work with:

- I cannot use a Pivot
- I cannot create a separate column to first extract the unique values, and then count those.

I've been trying to come up with a formula using `IF` and `COUNTUNIQUE`, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `query` directly to the output of `unique` without creating any extra columns in the sheet. The `unique` command, applied to a range, returns distinct rows, thus eliminating repeated Ids.

```
=query(unique(A:C), "select Col3, Col2, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2, Col3", 1)
```

The columns are referred to abstractly as Col1, Col2, Col3 because the `query` operates on an array contained in memory, not in the sheet.

Output:

```
Year    Region  count ID
2014    EU      1
2014    US      2
2015    US      1
```