# Google Sheets sum values for unique cells in single column and multiple IF conditions

Tags: google-sheets

My data:

```
A   B   C       D
D   150 hash123 2/3/2023
D   200 hash999 1/3/2023
D   200 hash999 1/3/2023
E   250 hash321 1/2/2023
E   265 hash954 1/2/2023
D   344 hash004 9/5/2022
B   434 hash075 8/5/2022
A   975 hash749 5/5/2022
C   513 hash304 1/5/2022
B   454 hash926 2/5/2021
```

For only the unique values in column C, I want to SUM the associated value of the same row in column B, if the value in column A is "D" and the date in column D is within the last 3 months.

So in the above that would be: 150 + 200 = 350.

I was working with `COUNTIFS`
`=COUNTIFS(D:D,">="&EDATE(TODAY(),-3),$A:$A,"D")`, but I think I need to combine it somehow with a `=query(unique(C:C),...)` but I don't know if and how.

I already checked [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101219/count-the-unique-values-in-a-column-based-on-criteria-in-2-different-columns), but that just counts the total unique values. And [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117216/using-unique-and-sum-for-all-possible-values-in-google-sheets), but that does not use `unique`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sortn()` and `query()`, like this:

```
=query( 
  sortn(A1:D, 9^9, 2, C1:C, true), 
  "select sum(Col2) 
   where Col1 = 'D' 
   and Col4 > date " & text(edate(today(), -3), "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " 
   label sum(Col2) '' ", 
   0 
)
```

See [sortn()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624) and [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343).

Comment: Thank you. This is only a small subset of my data though, the actual data is thousands of rows and dozens of columns (where the columns shown here are not next to each other). Would that change your solution? I'm asking in particular because of the `A1:D10` and `9x9` parts in your solution that in my scenario would have to apply to a far larger set. And secondly, why are you using `text` for the date range filter? Thanks!

Comment: Use an open-ended reference like `A2:D` to cover all the rows. The expression `9^9` gets the number `387,420,489` which is much larger than the number of rows in any spreadsheet you can create in Google Sheets. The `text()` function is required in order to get the ISO8601 date format required in date literals by the `query()` function.